# how to disable a class in migrate module

Tags: migrations

I have already deleted a migrate class in the .inc file and also deleted it in the .install file but i still get an error saying:

```
Class ForumTermMigration no longer exists
Class ForumUserMigration no longer exists
```

whenever i access the migrate UI in drupal site.

how to fix this?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Set up the move2drupal module module.
 */

function move2drupal_enable() {
  //Migration::registerMigration('ForumTermMigration');
  //Migration::registerMigration('ForumUserMigration');
  Migration::registerMigration('ForumNodeMigration');
  Migration::registerMigration('ForumCommentMigration');
  }

function move2drupal_uninstall() {
  // 
}

function move2drupal_disable() {
  //Migration::deregisterMigration('ForumTermMigration');
  //Migration::deregisterMigration('ForumUserMigration');
  Migration::deregisterMigration('ForumNodeMigration');
  Migration::deregisterMigration('ForumCommentMigration');
}
```

the above is my .install file. see ive commented the class i deleted in the .inc file.

I have also tried clearing the cache. uninstalling the module and reinstalling it again.

Comment: First thing: clear cache. Administer -> Configuration -> Performance.

Comment: done that already many times.

Comment: Can you uninstall migrate itself? Might be the simplest way to clear the data from wherever it's put it.

Comment: If I remember correctly it was in the `migrate_status` table, so you will have to delete it manually from MySQL. (However I am not entirely sure)

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using Drupal 7.22.

For my migration class, in my migrate_mypages.install file I have:

```
function migrate_mypages_enable() {
  Migration::registerMigration('MyPagesMigration');
}

function migrate_mypages_disable() {
  Migration::deregisterMigration('MyPages');
}
```

I haven't looked into the actual Migrate module, but it seems that when registering a migration in code, you have to use the full class name, whereas when de-registering the migration in code, you use only the name of your migration (machine-name).

If you are stuck with old classes, you can either add the de-register lines back in, and enable/disable your module, or, manually clear the class lines out of the table "migrate_status" in your database (as per Neograph734's comment).

As well, if you use drush, there is also:

```
drush migrate-deregister --orphans
```

Comment: If you're going to use drush as a quick fix anyway, you could also run the more targeted `drush php-eval "Migration::deregisterMigration('CLASSNAME');"` as that will only remove the classes you specify and not try to do anything more clever!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) for achieving this: Use `drush migrate-deregister --orphans`.

Comment: Super helpful! Also, the configuration admin page will list any orphaned migrations and provides a button to deregister them when they exist (admin/content/migrate/configure).